# Is jQuery passing the correct variable to my Django view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to figure out a way to let the end user delete items for sale (if they are the seller), via AJAX.  I'm sure my code below has more than few errors, but my question specifically is with the jQuery AJAX function below.

is 'id' taking the 'entryname' and sending it up to my views?  Did I do this correctly?

TEMPLATE.HTML

```
{% for entry in latest_entries %}
   entry.name <div class="delete_button" id="{{ entry.name }}">delete</div>
   entry.price
   entry.picture
   entry.sellername

{% endfor %}
```

JQUERY

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_button").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/storefront/",
            data: { entryname:id },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response.success);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

VIEWS.PY

```
latest_entries=Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]

@login_required
def delete_object(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      object_name = request.POST.get('entryname')
      Entry.objects.get(id=object_name).delete()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/storefront/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the id to the variable `id`

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

but you are sending the variable `entryname` (which does not exist so is `undefined`)

```
data: { entryname:entryname },
```

What you want it:

```
data: { entryname: id },
```

***Update***

You are also missing a `"`

```
 entry.name <div class="delete_button" id="{{ entry.name }}">delete</div>
```

Comment: Yep, although you are missing an `"` after `}}`

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
data: { entryname:entryname },
```

but no `entryname` variable defined. there is an `id` variable defined. Maybe it should be

```
data: { entryname:id },
```